# Experience points jumping and leveling for RP game

Tags: php, math

Sorry for the "half vague" title, but I couldn't come up with a better title.

Anyways, I'm building sort of an RP game with PHP and right now I'm trying to figure out how to advance the users level and keep the "overflow" of experience points and possibly advance their level again.

So let's say my character is level 1, I need 400 exp to reach level 2. Currently what I have is, when I reach 400 exp or over, it advances my level by one and resets my exp. But what I would like to do is if I gain 450 exp it advances my level and resets my exp to the overflow which is 50 in this case. This isn't hard, the tricky part is if I gain so much exp that I will level up more than once!

Currently I have this code,

```
    public function advLvl($user) {
        $sql = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `characters` SET `level` = `level` + 1, `experience` = '0' WHERE `u_name` = :user");
        $sql->execute(array(":user" => $user));
    }

    public function checkLvl($user, $currLvl) {
        $sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT `experience` FROM `characters` WHERE `u_name` = :user");
        $sql->execute(array(":user" => $user));
        $exp = $sql->fetchColumn();

        if($exp >= $this->expNextLevel($currLvl)) {
            $this->advLvl($user);
        }
    }

    public function expNextLevel($currLvl) {
        if($currLvl == 1) {
            return 400;
        }else {
            $gain = 400 + $this->defaultMobGain($currLvl);
            $expNextLevel = 120 + ($gain * $currLvl);
            return $expNextLevel;
        }
    }
```

And on every request I do this,

```
 $alt->checkLvl($_SESSION["username"], $char_info["level"]);
```

Which, increases my level, everything works, the only problem is that if I gain so much exp that I will advance more than once then it only increments per refresh. So let's say I am level 1 and I gain 1320 exp, that is enough to get me up to level 3 (level 1 = 400, level 2 = 920). But in order to keep up with the changes I have to refresh the page twice.

So I assume you have to build some kind of a recursive function. Something like,
while my current exp is greater than or equal to the amount of exp till the next level, advance my level. But, it's not as simple as that, that while loops is going to be executed hundreds of times, I only need it to execute twice (in this case). How would I go about doing this?

Hopefully it makes sense and you understand what I'm trying to accomplish, if you need more info then just let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you forget about resetting the experience points, so if the user wins, for example, 1920 exp, you'd just check how many levels  has been passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would store the total amount without resetting to zero. Then just do the math based on what level they're on.

Here is an example of what I'm suggesting. The exp required for each level is just hard-coded here, but could be calculated on the fly like you are doing (not sure what defaultModGain is doing so I just hard-coded).

```
function getLevel($exp) {
    $levels = array(0, 400, 920, 1320);

    for ($i = (count($levels) - 1); $i >= 0; $i--) {
        if ($exp >= $levels[$i]) {
            return $i + 1;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: In other words, don't increment. Keep track of the total number and compare to the number required for each level.

Comment: At first, I didn't want to store the exp required for each level but that would definitely be the easier way instead of reversing the algorithm for 2-3 levels each check. So I'm going to store them in an array and just compare the base level + 2 or 3 levels and check the exp of that.

Answer (score 2):

Like the others I recommend to not reset the experience points after a level up, but rather insert the difference between total experience - level total. Then recalculate the experience needed for a level up and recheck just after that. As long as the achieved experience is higher than the level up requirement, there should be a level up.